# m_pMainWnd is NULL in CWinApp, because InitInstance is not called

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a simple window using MFC, however the program terminates immediately and an output line from Debug seems strange:

```
d:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\VC7Libs\Ship\ATLMFC\Src\MFC\appcore.cpp(783) : AppMsg - Warning: m_pMainWnd is NULL in CWinApp::Run - quitting application.
```

After further inspection, I realize that CMyFrame::InitInstance doesn't get called. I have had some experience related to MFC, because I have used Win32++ (aka Win32xx) in Code::Blocks. Now I'm trying out VS Community 2019 while using the official MFC framework, but I am not capable of creating a blank window. Here is the complete code:

```cpp
//main.cpp
//Code taken from:
//www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_windows_fundamentals.htm

#include <afxwin.h>
#include <iostream>

class CMyFrame : public CFrameWnd {
public:
    CMyFrame() {
        Create(NULL, _T("MFC Application Tutorial"));
    }
};

class CExample : public CWinApp {
public:
    CExample() { std::cout << "CExample Constructor\n"; }
    ~CExample() { std::cout << "CExample Destructor\n"; }

    virtual BOOL InitInstance() {
        std::cout << "CExample InitInstance\n";
        CMyFrame* Frame = new CMyFrame();
        m_pMainWnd = Frame; //<--

        Frame->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
        Frame->UpdateWindow();

        return TRUE;
    }
};

CExample theApp;

int main() { return theApp.Run(); }
```

Console Output:

```
CExample Constructor
CExample Destructor

D:\Visual Studio Projects\Visual C++\MFC_Project\Debug\MFC_Project.exe (process 13012) exited with code 0.
```

Trying to manually call InitInstance in main triggers a runtime error. As long as I know, InitInstance should be called by MFC automatically. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Your code is basically okay, this looks like an issue with project settings. In MFC program you don't need `int main()`. You just put `CExample theApp;` and this will indirectly call `WinMain` entry point. But you have probably setup a console program and something weird is happening. Create a new project: C++ -> MFC -> MFC Application -> Dialog based application. Copy/Paste the above code in to the file for `CWinApp/CWinAppEx` class. You won't be able to use `std::cout` in a standard MFC app, use `TRACE` instead.

Comment: Thank you, letting VS create the project from its own templates got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did this source code come from? It does not appear to have been automatically generated by Visual Studio as it does not make sense.

MFC does not use `main()` nor does calling the `run()` method of `CWinApp` start up an MFC application.

See this documentation regarding the `run()` method which says that it starts the message pump. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=vs-2019#run which means that your application is not doing any of the initialization needed to set up the environment so that the message pump can actually process messages correctly.

> Run acquires and dispatches Windows messages until the application
>   receives a WM_QUIT message. If the application's message queue
>   currently contains no messages, Run calls OnIdle to perform idle-time
>   processing. Incoming messages go to the PreTranslateMessage member
>   function for special processing and then to the Windows function
>   TranslateMessage for standard keyboard translation; finally, the
>   DispatchMessage Windows function is called.
>
> Run is rarely overridden, but you can override it to provide special
>   behavior.

Allow Visual Studio to generate the proper skeleton for an MFC application which will create the necessary entry point for the application, link in all of the proper libraries, initialize the MFC runtime environment, and start the message pump to start handling the messages.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working creating the project with Visual Studio template 'MFC App'. I guess I should get use to create projects based on IDE's templates from now on. :)

Comment: @P.Rodríguez Microsoft provides the various templates, which depend on the specific target environment, because they are a pain free way to start a project. With MFC, as long as you are following the paradigm of MFC and how MFC works and expects an application to be structured, it is a fairly productive environment. There is a lot of stuff there and it provides a lot of the underlying plumbing needed for a Windows application. You can stretch it to some extent however it is easy to end up down a blind alley if you do not exercise reasonable planning, knowing what rules you can break or bend.